How the equivalence of two signals multiplication in time domain and corresponding frequency domain convolution actually works for discrete signals?
I'd like to show the equivalence of two signals multiplication in time domain and corresponding convolution of them in frequency domain in Python.
Direct multiplication of two signals in time domain and corresponding convolution in frequency domain won't get the expected result:
f = 2e6
t = np.linspace(0,1,64)

x = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*0.5*f*t)

# multiplication in time domain
signal_xy = x*y

# Fourier of multiplied signals and individual signal
FFT_xy = np.fft.fft(signal_xy)
FFT_x = np.fft.fft(x)
FFT_y = np.fft.fft(y)

n = FFT_x.shape[0]

# plot the result
plt.plot(abs(FFT_xy))
plt.plot(abs(np.convolve(FFT_x,FFT_y))[n:2*n]/len(x), linestyle='--')

which outputs:

the only way (that I've found for this moment) to get the expected result is just double one of the FFT signals (FFT_x or FFT_y):

but it looks like some hack. From this point I would conclude, that multiplication in time domain is the same as convolution in frequency domain, but with important clarification: two signals during convolution should be completely overlapped and the result of such convolution should be non less than the initial signal length.
Does it work in this way? and what should I do if I convolve two signals with the different length?
EDIT:
I also tried np.fft.fftshift for both FFT signals and used same mode in np.convolve, so the plotting command transformed to plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--'), the result was also incorrect:


What do you mean by double one of the FFT signals ? Increase the length by two? That is, zero pad by two?

@PeterK., no, just copy the signal

@Curious: do you know the difference between circular and linear convolution ?

@Hilmar I've added another canonical answer to Meta.

@Hilmar, not sure, that I know), maybe something similar as for DFT?

You have to fftshift() the signals before you convolve, otherwise it won't work. Also, you should use the 'same' option for computing the convolution as it will automatically index the convolution correctly. Here's a Matlab script I put together to demo.
% Script to demonstrate convolution/multiplication of FFTs
t = linspace(0,1,64);
f = 2e6;
c1 = sin(2*pi*f*t);
c2 = sin(2*pi*0.5*f*t);

x = sin(2*pi*f*t);
y = sin(2*pi*0.5*f*t);

signal_xy = x.*y;

FFT_xy = fft(signal_xy);
FFT_x = fft(x);
FFT_y = fft(y);

% Plot Different Signals
figure;
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(abs(FFT_xy))
subtitle('FFT of Multiplied Signal')
xlabel('Frequency (k)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(abs(conv(FFT_x,FFT_y,'same'))/length(FFT_x))
subtitle('Convolved FFTs no fftshift')
xlabel('Frequency (k)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(fftshift(abs(conv(fftshift(FFT_x),fftshift(FFT_y),'same')))/length(FFT_x))
subtitle('Convolved FFTs with fftshift')
xlabel('Frequency (k)')
ylabel('Amplitude')



I tried as you advised me plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--'), but still the result does not match

@Curious can you post the new code and graphs?

I didn't change the code at all, I just tried to use plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--') for comaring signals

also added the result with plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.convolve(np.fft.fftshift(FFT_x),np.fft.fftshift(FFT_y), 'same')))/len(FFT_x), linestyle='--')

@Curious the data just looks like it's rotated by one point for some reason. If you circularly shift it to the left by 1 space, it should give the right result. Maybe something weird with Numpy's fftshift, not sure.

or np.convolve, because I also tried to use fftshift from scipy library, result is exactly the same

@Curious that could also be the case.

nevertheless, I can use np.roll function by shifting the final result by -1, thank you so much for your answer, it conceptaully answers to my question)
